# Please find the most simplified expression for x(t)?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

For 1/6t*dx/dt=x sqrt((3t^2)-1)

I'm sorry but I really am not sure how to simplify this. Would I have to find the integral of both sides?

The choices for the answers are:

a) e^(2/3 sqrt((3t^2)-1)^3)

b) e^(2/3 sqrt((3t^2)-1)^3)+c

c) 2/3(((3t^2)-1)^2/3)+c

d) Ce^(2/3 sqrt((3t^2)-1)^3)

e) 2/3 sqrt(((3t^2)-1)^3)+c

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: if you use $$, it seems nice.

Comment: Hi Jack. Welcome! Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in future :)

Comment: Yes, 1/6t*dx/dt is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{6t}\frac{dx}{dt}=x\sqrt{3t^2-1}$$
$$\frac{dx}{x}=6t\sqrt{3t^2-1}dt$$
$$\int dx/x=ln|x|+c_1$$
$$3t^2-1=y,6tdt=dy,\int\sqrt y dy=\frac{2}{3}y^{3/2}$$
$$\int6t\sqrt{3t^2-1}dt=\frac{2}{3}(3t^2-1)^{3/2}+c_2$$

Comment: Thank you so much for showing each step. It makes it really easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint:
$$\frac{1}{6t}\frac{dx}{dt}=x \sqrt{3t^2-1}$$
$$\frac{dx}{x} = 6t\sqrt{3t^2-1}dt$$

Now integrate both sides of this equation. You can use $u$-substitution on the right hand side.

Comment: Good answer +1 . Yet no actual substitution needed: since $\;6t=(3t^2-1)'\;$ , we get an almost immediate integral: $$\int (3t^2-1)'\sqrt{3t^2-1} \,dt=\frac23(3t^2-1)^{3/2} +C$$

Comment: Thank you both, that hint really helps. Also thank you for the answer.